# Http Server Push with Netty + protobuf

Tags: comet, protocol-buffers, netty, server-push, bayeux

We're designing a communications system for supporting asynchronous near-realtime server pushing of events/messages to thousands of clients acrros JVM, .Net and mobile platforms. We have a mixed model (both publish-subscribe and request-response) and binary data.

We are using [Netty](http://netty.io/) and [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and we need to encapsulate all this in http(s).

We were looking into the [Bayeux Protocol](http://svn.cometd.com/trunk/bayeux/bayeux.html) and [its Netty implementation](http://code.google.com/p/bayeux4netty/) and were inclined to use a modified version of it with protobuf codecs instead of JSONs' or roll our own starting from the WebSockets example ([client](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/client/package-summary.html) and [server](http://netty.io/docs/stable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/package-summary.html)). For performance concerns we would stay out of Base64 encodings an the like.

Are there any implementations that we are missing? How feasible would it be to do a protobuf-based Bayeux protocol? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about [STOMP over Web Sockets](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/)?

Comment: We need to share port 80 with regular web traffic and split it via Apache mod_proxy on the frontend (netty's behind). We share the concerns expressed [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/290121/configuring-apache2-to-proxy-websocket).